# Attempting to prove $f(x,y)=\max\{x,y\}$ is convex using the Hessian matrix

Tags: convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which is defined by $f(x,y)=\max\{x,y\}$, is convex.

My lecturer proved this by showing (by definition) that $f(x\cdot t +(1-t)\cdot y)\leq t \cdot f(x)+(1-t)\cdot f(y).$

I can see how the proof by definition rolls out, I've tried a different approach and would like a review on weather it is correct or not:

We know that
$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x& x>y \\ y & y>x \end{array}\right.$

So I assumed it is differentiable, such that: $f_x(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1& x>y \\ 0 & y>x \end{array}
\right.$ and also:
$f_y(x,y)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0 & x>y \\
  1 & y>x
 \end{array}
\right.
$

And therefore: $
\operatorname{Hess}f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$, which means all of $\operatorname{Hess}f$ minors are $\geq0$, thus proving $f$ is convex.

One problem that came to mind is what happens when $x=y$, which cannot be solved by changing a finite number of points, because we're working over $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Any ideas/views on this proof are helpful in proving my understanding of this subject.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that $f$ is not differentiable. The difficulty is similar to proving $f(x)=|x|$ has a minimum at $0$.

Comment: I see the similarity, is the function $f(x)=|x|$ differentiable?

Comment: Note that all minors of your Hessian are also $\le 0$, proving $f$ is concave.  So something is wrong!  If you assume $f$ is differentiable (which is false), then you can prove whatever you want.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around why $f$ is not differentiable, care to elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried sketching a graph? Or writing down the limit quotient?

Comment: I can see how to graph of $f$ is undefined for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x=y$.    is that the reason why it is not differentiable?

if we would define $f$ in such a manner that $f(x,y)=x \leftarrow x\geq y$, and $f(x,y)=y \leftarrow y>x$, would that make $f$ differentiable?

Comment: With the same arguments you can show that $f(x) = -|x|$ is convex, which is absurd.